# Laravel: How to incorporate the returned value of the model's metod into a restrictive getting routine, optimally?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Consider the following:

```
public function getData() {
   $regions = Region::latest('id')->get();
   $requiredData = [];
   foreach ($regions as $region) {
      $requiredData[] = [
         'id' => $region->id,
         'name' => $region->name,
         'flag' => $region->flag,
         'cities' => $region->cityIds() // simply returns an array of Ids
      ];
   }
   return response()->json(compact('requiredData'));
}
```

If the `'cities'` was not "required", then the whole thing could've been simplified to:

```
$regions = Region::latest('id')->get(['id', 'name', 'flag']);
```

The `cityIds()` is just a method on the model, that is not suitable inside of the array argument passed to the method of [`get()`](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_get). Is there any *better* approach to avoid the seemingly *"redundant"* array of `$requiredData`, and/or to simplify and/or optimize the code?

Comment: From where does cityIds() retreives the values? Is it a relationship or something else?

Comment: @user8555937 It eventually gets the data from a relationship, and does some minor adjustments.

Answer (score 0):

> It eventually gets the data from a relationship, and does some minor adjustments.

The ideal way would be to define 'cities' as a relationship method and call it naturally when you need it. Since more logic is involved, you can use [mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators) to simulate 'cities' as an existing attribute. Inside `Region` model append the following:

```
// append a ghost column; see https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json
protected $appends = ['cities'];

// this mutator will retrieve the desired data as it would be a relationship
public function getCitiesAttribute($value)
{
    // load required relationships
    $this->load('relationship');

    // access relationships using $this
    $this->relationship;

    // process relationship and return data
    return $this->relationship->toArray();
}
```

You can then simply use

```
$regions = Region::latest('id')->get(['id', 'name', 'flag']);
```

And when you need the cities use

```
$regions->first()->cities;
```

I hope this answer helps you.

---

You can load the required relationships automatically when records are fetched from database. Use the following array:

```
protected $with = ['relationship1', 'relationship2.relationship3'];
```

I've no idea what your model structure is. For complex relations you should load them inline instead:

```
$regions = Region::latest('id')
              ->with('rel1', 'rel2')
              ->get(['id', 'name', 'flag']);
```

---

Use `$hidden` to hide the undesired columns and relationships:

```
protected $hidden = ['col1', 'rel1', 'rel2'];
```

`rel1` and `rel2` should be relationships methods name.

Comment: Thanks for your response; I want the respective "city Ids" on each and every instance readily generated in place, otherwise I already have the relationship established and the `cities` are retrieved as expected through a `foreach` loop! Also, following the "`$appends`" approach leaves the redundant "relashionship" fields in the final outcome!

Comment: See updated answer. Depending on your relationships type, you&#39;re gonna have to leave the `foreach` loop do the job, or load them manually.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a relationship between regions and cities, e.g. one-to-many, you can define that in the Region model like so:

```
public function cities() {
     return $this->hasMany('App\City');
}
```

and then just simply call `with`:

```
$regions = Region::latest('id')->with(['cities'])->get(['id', 'name', 'flag']);
```

It will give you all the fields from cities as well, but if you want only ids, change the relation to the following:

```
return $this->hasMany('App\City')->pluck('id');
```

Comment: Thanks for your response; eager-loading the relationship _undesirably_ pulls everything in! Also, the relationship methods are expected to return a ["relation"-related](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations.html) instance, not a [`Collection`](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html) returned by the [`pluck()`](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_pluck) method! Trying that resulted in an exception thrown as: _`Method Illuminate/Support/Collection::addEagerConstraints does not exist.`_